# Execute current file outside of working directory

Tags: working-directory

I know I can execute the current file, lets say a bash file, with `:! bash %`.
But what can I do if I want to execute the current file in a different directory (such as the location of the current file) than the current vim working directory. 
I know that I could change to the working directory of the current file by `:cd %:p:h` and then execute the file but then I would need to jump back again.

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `cd` to the interesting directory inside the script?

Comment: yeah sure could do that but I would like to avoid to hard code the location since I will need to execute it on another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possibilities, but I think you'd either have to jump back (`cd -`), or execute the command in a subshell; e.g.:

```
:! cd somedir; bash ~-/% ; cd -

:! bash -c 'cd somedir ; bash ~-/%'
```

Comment: thanks a lo t!  ':cd %:p:h ; bash %:t ; cd -' works as I hoped

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint from the [other answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3601). It largely works. But keep typing all those ":cd ...; bash ...; cd -" MULTIPLE TIMES are so bothersome.

In my case, I was going to do a bunch of shell commands. More precisely, I started my vim in repo_foo, AND also open some files in helper repo_bar. Later I realized I would need to do several git commands in that helper repo_bar. I ended up shell out to the repo_bar's directory, by:

```
:!cd %:p:h; bash
```

I do NOT need to do `cd -` to go back to my original working directory, because when I later `exit` the sub-shell, it will automatically go back to the parent shell with the original working directory intact.